# Remove lines from csv array of hashes

Tags: perl

I am trying to remove all lines from the array that contains a ':' character. This is a part of a bigger system so I can't change much of the interface nor am I an expert in perl.

I Started With This:

```
sub read_file {
    my $file = shift;
    my $aoh  = csv(in => $file, headers => {'a' => 'aa'});

    foreach my $row (@$aoh) {
        # trim any spurious leading/trailing space (in-place edit)
        do { s/^\s+//; s/\s+$// } for values %$row;

        # convert start/end bit values to be zero-based
        for my $foo ('c', 'd') {
            if ($row->{$foo} =~ /^\d+$/) {
                $row->{$bit} -= 100;
            }
        }
    }

    return $aoh;
}
```

I tried this

```
sub read_file {
    my $file = shift;
    my $aoh  = csv(in => $file, headers => {'a' => 'aa'});
    my $aohf = grep { substr($_->{'a'}, 0, 1) eq ":" } @$aoh;

    foreach my $row (@$aohf) {
        # trim any spurious leading/trailing space (in-place edit)
        do { s/^\s+//; s/\s+$// } for values %$row;

        # convert start/end bit values to be zero-based
        for my $foo ('c', 'd') {
            if ($row->{$foo} =~ /^\d+$/) {
                $row->{$bit} -= 100;
            }
        }
    }

    return $aohf;
}
```

After trying a few different things I keep getting an error similar to this: 
`Can't use string ("5") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your line:

```
my $aohf = grep { substr($_->{'a'}, 0, 1) eq ":" } @$aoh;
```

you are assigning the result of `grep` to a scalar (`$aohf`).

And according to `perldoc -f grep`:

```
In scalar context, [it] returns the number of times the
expression was true.
```

Therefore, you are assigning a number (probably "5", by the looks of your error) to `$aohf`.  And in the very next line of code, you are trying to de-reference this "5" as an array with `@$aohf`.  That's not going to work.

You probably intended to write the `grep` line to assign to an array, like this:

```
my @aohf = grep { substr($_->{'a'}, 0, 1) eq ":" } @$aoh;
```

Then, you can write the first line of your foreach loop like this, without the need to de-reference anything:

```
foreach my $row (@aohf) {
```

So basically, you assign to an array, and use an array.  No de-referencing needed!  (This is simpler than assigning to a scalar, and then attempting to de-reference the scalar into an array.)

Try out my changes, and see if they work for you.

---

**EDIT:**

The original code returned `$aoh`, which is a reference to an array.  If you still want to return a reference to an array in the new code, you can change the `return` statement to:

```
return \@aohf;
```

The `\` before the `@aohf` gets the reference to the `@aohf` array, which is then returned to the calling code.

Comment: This worked, however, the function using the return is not happy because it is a different data type how do I convert the array back into a scaler?

Comment: You'll want to return `\@aohf`, which returns a reference to an array, just like the old code did.  (I added this to the `EDIT` section of my reply, which covers it in a little more detail.)